# InfluxDB Schema Design (Long and thin vs short and fat?

Tags: database, database-design, time-series, schema, influxdb

I am planning the schema design for the database. Does InfluxDB perform better with "short and fat" designs or "long and thin".

I tend to prefer long and thin as they are easier to scale and they are apparently more stable?

Can anybody offer more insight here?

Thanks

***Edit to show Yuri the data:***

**Proposed schema design:**

[image: Proposed schema design]

This design will scale which is good - it handles static data i.e. interval 0, interval data and other future sources I'll be adding in. What I'm not sure about is whether I should aim to fit everything into a single database and if it might be better to break the data up into multiple databases?

It is in slight contrast to designs such as this however (source: https://medium.com/coinograph/storing-and-processing-billions-of-cryptocurrency-market-data-using-influxdb-f9f670b50bbd)

[image: Price and Volume interval data]

Thanks Yuri!

Comment: https://community.influxdata.com/t/wide-rows-vs-short-rows/3410
I haven't been able to find a conclusive answer for this

Answer (score 1):

First things first: there's s such thing as "schema" in Influx as you may know it from RDBMS world.

'cause that's not any kind of SQL DB - essentially, it's a key-value with a specific point-in-time key & complex value, consisting of combination of low-cardinality indexed kv-pairs & high-cardinality actual series of named values.

It scales & tunes differently than the ways you've learned from RDBMS, hence.

And the "schema" itself is pretty fluid there, it's none of a rigid.

So, I suggest you to rely solely on your needs: how your data is (or supposed to be) shaped & what you suppose to do with it.

If you give me a sample of that - I'd probably be able to give you an example of what would be the best way to handle it in Influx.

Comment: Continuing on... I think the problem with this design is whilst it's good in the sense that it can scale to multiple datasets. I lose some of the functionality though with functions in Influxdb. e.g. if i want to scale up minute interval data to daily data it is harder with this current design.